# Drag & Drop Label Text into the TextBlock in UWP

Tags: drag-and-drop, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have some content in textblock. i need to drag and drop the text from labels to fill the statements. It is like to fill in the blanks of some string using drag and drop.
(For eg: The target text block contains "UWP is __ platform-homogeneous application architecture created __ Microsoft __ first introduced __ Windows 10" and in gridview i have individual labels as "**a**","**by**","**and**","**in**". I need to drag the word and drop in the blank area to complete the following statement "UWP is a platform-homogeneous application architecture created by Microsoft and first introduced in Windows 10") I am trying to achieve in UWP using C#.please help me to do this.
[Click here to view the sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mSPj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved your requirement based on [`DragAndDropSampleManaged`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) UWP official code sample. For your requirement, you want to insert text such as  "a","by","and","in" into existed sentence via `drag and drop`. So you should get the range which your want to insert into . You could use `GetRangeFromPoint` (RichEditBox) method to get the range where your pointer hovered as the following :

```
private void TargetTextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetPosition(TargetTextBox);
    var range = TargetTextBox.Document.GetRangeFromPoint(point, Windows.UI.Text.PointOptions.ClientCoordinates);
    TargetTextBox.Document.Selection.SetRange(range.StartPosition - 1, range.EndPosition);       
    TargetTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
}
```

[image]
The text will be inserted into specific range when the point released.

```
private async void TargetTextBox_Drop(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DragEventArgs e)
{
     VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Outside", true);
     bool hasText = e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text);
     // if the result of the drop is not too important (and a text copy should have no impact on source)
     // we don't need to take the deferral and this will complete the operation faster
     e.AcceptedOperation = hasText ? DataPackageOperation.Copy : DataPackageOperation.None;
     if (hasText)
     {
         var text = await e.DataView.GetTextAsync();           
         TargetTextBox.Document.Selection.Text = text;
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you Nico Zhu. I also need to replace some character by the dragging content. For ex: I need to replace the `__` by the input(dragged) string.Kindly go through the sample image in my question.need to find the position of the string `__` and could be replace by the input in same position.(Note: I have multiple replaceable string(`__`) in the Target content. ). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, You could modify your selection range for containing specific character such as "_".

Comment: Thank you Nico zhu. It works fine, could you please give me an idea to replace only `__`. The dragging content will replace the content only it is dragged over the `__`. It do not replace the other string. Because my requirement is a Question & Answer type. User can drag the answer over the question content and can drop it in the blanks.That is only dragging over the `__`. It do not affect the question.I hope you can understand my requirement

Comment: For your requirement, you could use no outline TextBox  replace  "__" during one sentence. And copy text such as "a","by","and","in" to outline TextBox  via drag and drop. If you think this answer helps, please consider accept it !

Comment: Sorry NicoZhu.. I cant get you. But your answer is great and it works me perfectly for some other functions. Thanks for your effort. Now i need exactly what i have mentioned in my last comment.  Can you please give me an example as you mentioned in your previous comment.

Comment: Is there any possible to find the position of  `__` areas in Richeditbox?And so while we drag the content, if the mouse pointer reached that position(approximately) we can drop there. other wise let it not drop. any idea?